# agreggate de subdocumento para api getone

Tags: api, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hola estoy intentando obtener un objeto por "_id" pero no me funciona esta es mi api estoy usando mongoose y express.
este es mi model

```
const hotelesSchema = new Schema({
   "nombre": String,
   "direccion": String,
   "telefono": String,
   "estrellas": String,
   "precio": String,
   "imagenes": String
})

const mainSchema = new Schema({
   hoteles: [ hotelesSchema ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('hotel', mainSchema);
```

esta son mis rutas "solamente esta el get y el get-one ":

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const hotel = require('../models/hotel')

//getting all
router.get('/', async (req,res) => {

    try{
        const hotels = await hotel.find()
        res.json(hotels)
    } catch(err){
        res.status(508).json( {message: err.message})
    }    

})
//getting one
router.get('/:id', getHotel, (req,res) => {
    res.json(res.hotelf)   
})
module.exports = router
```

hasta aca todo muy bien el problema radica en el siguiente agreggate que uso para obtener de mongo db con el siguiente esquema [https://mongoplayground.net/p/MDL8AtQiVur] simulandolo en mongo play me funciona pero en mi proyecto no la respuesta que obtengo es : [ ]

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const hotel = require('../models/hotel')

async function getHotel(req,res,next){
    let hotelf 
    let parms = req.params.id
    try{
        hotelf = await hotel.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              _id: "5e1ea07583488e46ee528301"
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              hoteles: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$hoteles",
                  as: "hotel",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$hotel._id",
                      "5e1ea07583488e46ee528302"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              _id: 0
            }
          },
          {
            $unwind: "$hoteles"
          }
        ])
          console.log(hotelf) 

        if(hotelf==null){
            return res.status(404).json({message: 'cannot find hotel'})
            }
        } catch (err){
            return res.status(500).json({message: err.message})
        }
        res.hotelf = hotelf
        next ()
    }
```

Es decir necesito por medio de la funcion de arriba, que es simplemente un agreggate me de como resultando en mi proyecto el objeto que busco por id
ej:

```
[
  {
    "hoteles": {
      "_id": "5e1ea07583488e46ee528302",
      "direccion": "Centro",
      "estrellas": "4",
      "imagenes": "https://i.ibb.co/vcyqQSf/Soratama.jpg",
      "nombre": "Hotel Soratama",
      "precio": "540000",
      "telefono": "3204545"
    }
  }
]
```

Perdon por extenderme tanto pero quiero ser lo mas consiso posible, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola steven. Te puedo preguntar por que no exportas `hotelesSchema` y luego lo enlazas con `objectId` en `mainSchema`? Te ahorraria la dificultad del `aggregate`

Comment: Hola me podrías ejemplificar como lo harias?

Answer (score 0):

Creas tu schema de esta manera:

```
const hotelSchema = new Schema({
   "nombre": String,
   "direccion": String,
   "telefono": String,
   "estrellas": String,
   "precio": String,
   "imagenes": String
})
//Solo que aqui lo exportas y creara una tabla.
module.exports = mongoose.model('hotel', hotelSchema);
```

Este otro modelo es el que va a juntar de alguna manera. (Pero no creo que se necesite si no lo vas a relacionar.

```
const conjuntoDeHotelesYOtrasCosasSchema= new Schema({
   hoteles: [ {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "hotel",
   }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('hotelesYOtrasCosas', conjuntoDeHotelesYOtrasCosasSchema);
```

El ultimo schema se puede omitir y para obtener los hoteles accedes de esta manera.

```
const hotel = require('ruta/a/hotel.js)

///....Dentro del request

hotel.findById('tuId')
.exec()
.then(hotel=> {

   if(!hotel) trhow 'No existe el hotel'

   hotel.modificarAlgo = 'Modificas aqui'

  return hotel.save()

})
.then(hotelModificado=>{

  //..Tu response por aqui...
})
.catch(//...Capturas los errores)
```